# What image to use when pushing back to repository in Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I understand this documentation https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/push-back-to-your-repository/ but it does not tell you which image you should use for pushing back.

Does this mean that any image you use will have git installed on the container? If not, what is the best image to use for pushing back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You choose the docker image and therefore it could be anything that has anything installed. I suspect that most images will have git installed.

I just use, and it does have it installed (although not git-lfs)

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2
```